# Как запушить не забирая и не сливая?

Tags: git

не удалось отправить некоторые ссылки в «https://github.com/fdsfsd/Project.git»

```
подсказка: Обновления были отклонены, так как внешний репозиторий содержит
подсказка: изменения, которых у вас нет в вашем локальном репозитории.
подсказка: Обычно, это связанно с тем, что кто-то уже отправил изменения в 
подсказка: то же место. Перед повторной отправкой ваших изменений, вам нужно
подсказка: забрать и слить изменения из внешнего репозитория себе
подсказка: (например, с помощью «git pull …»).
подсказка: Для дополнительной информации смотрите «Note about fast-forwards»
подсказка: в «git push --help».
```

Как запушить, не забирая и не сливая?

Comment: Никак, гит не даст вам запушить изменения, пока вы не заберете изменения, ибо какой смысл в гите, если бы каждый мог пушить, что угодно и когда угодно?

Comment: @stackanon А git push origin --force не поможет?

Comment: @Gikas, поможет, если не боитесь, что коллеги потом руки вырвут.

Comment: можно отправить изменения в новую ветку

Comment: Скажите, а вы какую задачу хотите решить этими действиями? От реальной задачи очень сильно зависит ответ.

Answer (score 3):

1. если вы не против создать проблемы другим пользователям общего хранилища, можете перезаписать историю в этом общем хранилище, добавив опцию `-f` (`--force`):

   ```
   $ git push -f
   ```
2. а можете отправить свои изменения в новую ветку.

   1. обычно удобно создать ветку локально, а потом отправить её (под таким же именем) в общее хранилище:

      ```
      $ git checkout -b новая-ветка
      $ git push -u origin новая-ветка
      ```
   2. но можно и без создания новой локальной ветки:

      ```
      $ git push origin текущая-ветка:новая-ветка
      ```